# Ruby Gem ActiveAdmin Install Error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, installation, activeadmin

i am trying to install ActiveAdmin Gem i get the following error. i am running it from the commandline

```
harsha@harshamv:~$ gem install activeadmin
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyResolutionError)
    conflicting dependencies arel (~> 2.0.2) and arel (~> 4.0.0)
  Activated arel-4.0.0 via:
    arel-4.0.0 (~> 4.0.0), activerecord-4.0.0.rc2 (= 4.0.0.rc2), rails-4.0.0.rc2 (< 4, >= 3.0.0), activeadmin-0.6.3 (= 0.6.3)
  instead of (~> 2.0.2) via:
    meta_search-1.0.0 (~> 1.0), activeadmin-0.6.3 (= 0.6.3)
```

Comment: Can you by chance link your Gemfile?

Comment: @JulioGMedina oh okay. i was trying to set up my environment first :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Rails 4, you need to use `>= 1.0.0.pre` version of ActiveAdmin. The best way of doing that right now is:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

in your Gemfile.